# Issue with posting arraylist with indexed properties from jsp to action class

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, arraylist, struts

I'm having this issue where I have dynamically generated values in hidden inputs like so:

```
<div id="items-div" class="selection-div">
    <input name="selectedItem[0].articleName" id="selectedItem" type="hidden" value="cereal"></input>
    <input name="selectedItem[0].quantity" id="selectedItem" type="hidden" value="2"></input>
    <input name="selectedItem[1].articleName" id="selectedItem" type="hidden" value="yogurt"></input>
    <input name="selectedItem[1].quantity" id="selectedItem" type="hidden" value="10"></input>
</div>
```

I append these to the items-div using jquery depending on what the user chooses on-screen, each of those is an Item.

```
public class Item {

    private String articleName = "";
    private int quantity = 0;

    public String getArticleName() {
        return articleName;
    }
    public void setArticleName(String articleName) {
        this.articleName = articleName;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

And this is the form class which has an ArrayList of these items

```
public class CreateArticleForm extends ActionForm {

    private ArrayList<Item> selectedList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public Item getSelectedItem(int index) {
        if (selectedList == null) {
            selectedList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        }
        while (index >= selectedList.size()) {
            selectedList.add(new Item());
        }

        return (Item) selectedList.get(index);
    }
    public ArrayList<Item> getSelectedList() {
        return selectedList;
    }
    public void setSelectedList(ArrayList<Item> selectedList) {
        this.selectedList = selectedList;
    }

}
```

And finally the action class

```
public class CreateArticleAction extends
        Action {

    public ActionForward executeAction(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, User user)
            throws Throwable {

            CreateArticleForm articleForm = (CreateArticleForm) form;
            //... do stuff
    }

}
```

I would expect that on post all the server would round up all the selectedItem[X] and call the getSelectedItem to build up the arraylist and populate it then set the properties to each object but when I submit the page on debug, I see the selectedList arraylist comes up empty. I am using this logic based from a previous assignment where instead the information with indexed properties was instead generated when the page was first loaded and then printed with a logic:iterate tag and then each input had a indexed="true" property, but since in this case it is from what the user clicks on the page, I instead use jquery to fill out the "items-div" with what the user is choosing, but it should be the same no? Am I missing something? It ran previously just fine... Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:** The above works if I hard-code test hidden inputs in the jsp page, it submits those but not the ones dynamically created and appended with jquery.

```
    $('.items-div').append($('<input/>').attr({ 
type : 'hidden', name: 'selectedItem['+index+'].articleName', id : 'selectedItem', value: objItem.articleName}));
```

Comment: In your generated code, ids should be unique for each element on the page. Also, input tags to not have separate close tags.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remove those ids and see if that's what is keeping it from working

As for the inputs, I noticed that as well and it bugged me, given that I use the below code to append those inputs and they should be posted as <input  /> but when I load up the page they look like that...  

     
    `$('.selection-div').append($('<input/>').attr({`
`type : 'hidden', name: 'selectedItem['+index+'].articleName', id : 'selectedItem', value: objItem.articleName}));`

Comment: No dice, only working currently if I hardcode the inputs, but not with ones appended with jquery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've known since before, but apparently it's a security measure to only allow elements that had been originally rendered to be posted back, so the ones I hard-coded worked just fine, but any others appended -after- rendering won't be submitted so I will probably have to put the objects in an array of objects, JSONfiy them and send them as a string to the action class, using an existing hidden input.